# After modifying the test,cypress is not instantly running' the tests in Electron browser

Tags: cypress

I am using Atom.js editor for creating or modifying the 'example-spec.js' tests in Cypress.io. After modifying the test, 'cypress is not instantly running' the tests in Electron browser. Each time I need to close the browser and open again to get the latest changes applied in tests. 
I have read the documents and ensured that 'watchForFileChanges' is set to true in cypress.json file under the integration folder or didn't specify the 'watchForFileChanges' in the cypress.json (default behavior, cypress will run the test instantly without the 'watchForFileChanges' ). What could be the issue here?

```
{
"watchForFileChanges": true
}
```

Version details:
Windows operating system 8.1 version,
Cypress version : Beta version 3.10 ,
Electron browser : 59,
Chrome: 68,
Atom.Js editor version : 1.29.0,
Node version: v8.11.4

Comment: You're running your tests with `cypress open` in this case, correct?

Comment: Yes, Joshua. In windows from the command prompt, i have run the command c:/node_modules/.bin/cypress  open ....then I have opened the 'example-spec.js' file in Atom.js editor under from the integration folder. I have tried running with Chrome 68 and Electron 59 browsers...